# AFNetworking Square API

Tags: curl, nsurlconnection, afnetworking, square, square-connect

I'm really stumped on this. I need to convert this cURL command into objective-c. I am using the AFNetworking library to go about this but it returns bad request (error 400) each time.  I'd appreciate help.

**cURL command**:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXX" -d '{"quantity_delta": -5,"adjustment_type": "SALE"}' https://connect.squareup.com/v1/me/inventory/00CC0141-C50C-4A7A-9FAA-368EC79DA652
```

**AFNetworking Objective-C Code**:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXX" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"quantity_delta": [NSNumber numberWithInt:-1], @"adjustment_type": @"SALE"};
NSLog(@"Parameters are %@", parameters);

[manager POST:@"https://connect.squareup.com/v1/me/inventory/00CC0141-C50C-4A7A-9FAA-368EC79DA652" parameters:@{@"quantity_delta": [NSNumber numberWithInt:-1], @"adjustment_type": @"SALE"} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: The endpoint path in the AFNetworking sample appears incorrect—it includes /items/ instead of /inventory/. If you make that change, does the request succeed?

Comment: Yes, I just realized that too. It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fair warning that I'm new to the AFNetworking library, but I was able to make a successful request by adding the line in bold between the first two lines of the above sample:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager setRequestSerializer:[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer]];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXX" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

It appears that by default, the `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` uses the `AFHTTPRequestSerializer`, which does *not* format JSON bodies correctly out of the box. Using the `AFJSONRequestSerializer` subclass instead resolves this issue.

Comment: Thanks a ton. You just saved me a huge headache!

Comment: For anyone who wants it, I made a github repository. https://github.com/greggmojica/SquareConnect